# Invalid product id with IAP only with iPad

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My in-app purchases do not work with the iPad but work pretty well via the iPhone. From the technology and logic part, it shouldn't be like that. I can not find any info connected to that issue. As I saw in the terminal, it returns an invalid product identifier if I run it on the iPad simulator. But with simulation on all iPhone models, everything runs well. It should not be like that because referencing the official documentation works the same on both systems.

Here is the fetching function:

```
public func fetchProducts(){
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(Product.allCases.compactMap({ $0.rawValue })))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
```

I call it like that:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        IAPManager.shared.fetchProducts()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        return true
    }
```

And that function is a part of the Singleton class.

So when I tried to buy an Item I retrieved that in terminal, because the array of fetched products was empty. With iPhones, the function works correctly and fetches all the products.

```
2022-12-15 17:53:46.397764+0100 Quotely[63397:3419642] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
```

Comment: Please update your question with a few more details. 1 - Is this a single, universal app for all iOS devices or do you have two apps - one for iPhone and one for iPad? 2 - Is this issue happening while running IAP in "Xcode" mode, "Sandbox" mode, or via TestFlight? 3 - while the code should be the same for any device, it wouldn't hurt to post your relevant code that returns the invalid product identifier error. Feel free to show a fake product id but otherwise post actual code (as text).

Comment: I have that problem while running on the x-code. Firstly I realized that my app had that problem after rejection from apple when I tried to upload the app to the App Store. They said: "You should implement IAP to sell products in App Store" but I had implemented it. Because they checked it with the iPad inspector and rejected the version. And after that, I found that when I fetch product IDs, all work well with iPhone, but with iPad it returns an Invalid product id. That is a universal app for all iOS devices so that should work the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, maybe someone else will come across a similar one. I just created a new StoreKit configuration file and everything started working fine with it.